# Server request performace: Get a lot of images with one call

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview, that contain an image for each cell. Since there will be quite a lot of cell, is it possible to package all the images needed, and retrive them with one request, or do you have to request each and every image separate? Trying to reduce the stress for on server. Or is this the normal way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you storing image name in database or the whole image as BLOB?

Comment: in which way you retrieve the images? is there ajax involved? php render via mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should just load the images asynchronously, more than dealing with such an optimization. As you ask, yes, this is the normal way to do that, unless your server has really *huge* traffic (*huge* = google.com, facebook.com, etc.).

I use the [SDWebImage open source library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and it works really well, making it transparent to you. After importing it, for each cell, you should do:

```
[cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyPlaceholderImage"]];
```

and it will try to load (and cache) dynamically each image, placing a placeholder image while it's loading.

I use it in a table with 100+ rows and it works like a charm.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you need, you can serve a collection of images as a zip file.

(And how do you do that?  It depends.  I don't know if the images are static or dynamic.)

Answer (score -1):

try converting the image in base64 formate and then send it

Comment: That will make the images bigger.

Comment: check this link [base64](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/23/when-you-should-use-base64-for-images/)

Comment: That's for embedding images directly in HTML.  When you're writing a native app, base64 just makes images bigger and *dosn't* reduce the number of requests.